# React custom dropdown with event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, addeventlistener

I created a `Dropdown` that when I click outside of it the dropdown disappears. I used a click event listener to determine if I clicked outside the dropdown.

After a few clicks, the page slows down and crashes. Perhaps the state is being rendered in a loop or too many events are being fired at once?

How do I fix this?
Also, is there a more React way to determine if I clicked outside an element? (Instead of using a document.body event listener)

Here is the codepen:

```js
const items = [
    {
        value: 'User1'
    },
    {
        value: 'User2'
    },
    {
        value: 'User3'
    },
    {
        value: 'User4'
    },
    {
        value: 'User5'
    }
];
    
class Dropdown extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isActive: false,
  }

  render() {
    const { isActive } = this.state;
    document.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
        if (evt.target.closest('#dropdownContent')) {
          //console.warn('clicked inside target do nothing');
          return;
        }

        if (evt.target.closest('#dropdownHeader')) {
          //console.warn('clicked the header toggle');
          this.setState({isActive: !isActive});
        }

        //console.warn('clicked outside target');
        if (isActive) {
          this.setState({isActive: false});
        }
      });
    
      return (
          <div id="container">
              <div id="dropdownHeader">select option</div>
              {isActive && (
                <div id="dropdownContent">
                  {items.map((item) => (
                    <div id="item" key={item.value}>
                      {item.value}
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              )}
          </div>
      );
  };
}
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Dropdown items={items} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#dropdownHeader {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 12em;
    padding: 0.2em 0 0.2em 0.2em;
    margin: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 3px rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15);
}

#dropdownContent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 12em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15);
    padding: 0.2em;
}

#item {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 0.75em 1em 0.75em 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Um, you don't need to link to your code. You can provide a runnable example free, online inside your question.

Comment: @zixuan is there a way to make reactjs code runnable inside your question?

Comment: oh never did it before. let me try again

Comment: sorry but you can convert it to standard JS @ngood97

Comment: Made it runnable inside question -- thanks for quick feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty simple explanation for what you're experiencing. :)

The way I was able to figure it out was the number of warnings that were showing up in the terminal every time I clicked somewhere was getting higher and higher, *especially when the state changed*.

The answer though is that since you were adding the event listener code in the render function, every time the code re-rendered it would add more and more event listeners slowing down your code.

Basically the solution is that you should move the adding of event listeners to `componentDidMount` so it's only run once.

Updated working javascript:

```
    const items = [
        {
            value: 'User1'
        },
        {
            value: 'User2'
        },
        {
            value: 'User3'
        },
        {
            value: 'User4'
        },
        {
            value: 'User5'
        }
    ];

class Dropdown extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isActive: false,
  }

  // added component did mount here
  componentDidMount(){
    const { isActive } = this.state;
    document.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
        if (evt.target.closest('#dropdownContent')) {
          console.warn('clicked inside target do nothing');
          return;
        }

        if (evt.target.closest('#dropdownHeader')) {
          console.warn('clicked the header toggle');
          this.setState({isActive: !isActive});
        }

        console.warn('clicked outside target');
        if (isActive) {
          this.setState({isActive: false});
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { isActive } = this.state;
    //removed event listener here
      return (
          <div id="container">
              <div id="dropdownHeader">select option</div>
              {isActive && (
                <div id="dropdownContent">
                  {items.map((item) => (
                    <div id="item" key={item.value}>
                      {item.value}
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              )}
          </div>
      );
  };
}
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Dropdown items={items} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```